Difference between memcpy and assigning array element when storing a pointer to an integer array
What are the differences between memcpy and assigning array element in storing a pointer (8 bytes) into an integer (4 bytes) array?
For example, I have an array of 32 integers (arr) and I want to use memory size of the last 2 integers (arr[30] and arr[31]) to store a pointer (p). Using memcpy I can write:
// store the pointer
auto address = reinterpret_cast<int*>(p);
std::memcpy(&Memory[30], &address, sizeof(address));

// retrieve the pointer
int *ptr;
std::memcpy(&ptr, &Memory[30], sizeof(ptr));

// test - succeed
assert(ptr == p);

To assign the array elements, I can write:
// store the pointer
auto address = reinterpret_cast<int*>(p);
Memory[30] = address[0];
Memory[31] = address[1];

// retrieve the pointer
int *ptr;
std::memcpy(&ptr, &Memory[30], sizeof(ptr));

// test - failed
assert(ptr == p);

But it seems like only the first version gives me the correct answer when I check ptr with assert(ptr == p).
Why the second version fails?

They differ due to endianness.

The second example doesn't use p except in the assert. You are saving one value, but asserting against another. Are p and global related somehow?

@IgorTandetnik Sorry, it should be global instead of p in the second version.

The piece of code introduced with "Using for-loop assignment, I can write" doesn't in fact contain a for-loop.

The first snippet copies the value of address to Memory. The second snippet copies the value pointed to by address to Memory.

The first fragment copies the address stored in p - it copies the memory where p itself is located. The second fragment copies the value pointed to by p, the value in memory that p points to. In other words, the first one is equivalent to memcpy(..., &p, sizeof(p)) while the second is memcpy(..., p, 2*sizeof(Memory[30])); the important difference is between &p in one case and p in the other.

@IgorTandetnik I think there's an implied sizeof(int*) == 2 * sizeof(int) in the question.

@Barmar That's not really important; it's possible that sizeof(p) == 2*sizeof(Memory[30]). but that's not the crux of the matter. The two fragments copy two different pieces of memory, even if those pieces are of the same size. And no, this has nothing to do with endianness.

@IgorTandetnik @IgorG I see the problem. But is there a way I can implement the code by assigning to the array element? I tried Memory[30] = (int)address; Memory[31] = (int)((char*)address + 4);, but it does not compile.

int* address = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&p); Memory[30] = address[0]; Memory[31] = address[1]; Note the ampersand; it's important. Anyway, while I expect this will work in practice, I'm pretty sure it's formally undefined behavior (UB), a form of type punning. Why do you want to store a pointer in an int array in the first place? It's UB just waiting to happen.

@IgorTandetnik I want to implement a linked-list style data structure that runs both on cpu and gpu with little overhead. Say the data structure is of 128 bytes and the last 2 bytes are used for storing the address of the next object. I need to perform bit operations in the first 126 bytes (e.g., checking a certain bit is 1 or not), and I feel like using an array is the easiest way to do so.

Would something like this do? struct Data { std::array<int, 126> data; Data* next;}; I must admit I know nothing about GPU programming beyond the fact that it exists.

@IgorTandetnik I think so. But do you think I should use std::array or regular array? struct Data { char data[126]; Data* next;}; I am not sure if std::array<char, 126> takes exactly 126 bytes. I want to make sure Data takes exactly 128 bytes since it's good for maintaining high memory throughput.

You can put a static_assert(sizeof(Data)==128) somewhere near the definition of Data. I'm confused though - do you expect a pointer to fit into two bytes? Are you working with a 16-bit microcontroller or something? Previously, you were trying to fit it into to ints.

@IgorTandetnik I made a typo there. I am working with 64 bit address. You are correct, it should be int instead of char. { int data[30]; Data* next;}
